# XSLT remove duplicate element values

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MD_LegalConstraints>
    <otherConstraints><CharacterString>Test 1</CharacterString></otherConstraints>
    <otherConstraints><CharacterString>Test 2</CharacterString></otherConstraints>
    <otherConstraints><CharacterString>Test 1</CharacterString></otherConstraints>
    <otherConstraints><CharacterString>Test 3</CharacterString></otherConstraints>
</MD_LegalConstraints>
```

I want to translate the xml above as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<rights>
    <rightsStatement>Test 1</rightsStatement>
</rights>
<rights>
    <rightsStatement>Test 2</rightsStatement>
</rights>
<rights>
    <rightsStatement>Test 3</rightsStatement>
</rights>
</data>
```

I try to follow ([XSL to remove duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267805/xsl-to-remove-duplicate-records)) to transform and remove the duplicate values. But it still contains the duplicate values (xslt version = 2.0)

```
<xsl:key name="legal-text" match="otherConstraints" use="."/>
<xsl:template match="MD_LegalConstraints">
<data>
<xsl:for-each select="otherConstraints[count(. | key('legal-text', .)[1]) = 1]">
<rights>
<rightsStatement>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</rightsStatement>
</rights>
</xsl:for-each>
</data>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you fix the input sample to be well-formed XML? Also make the XSLT sample minimal but complete to allow us to easily test it.

Comment: And if it is XSLT 2 you can also use `for-each-group` instead of a key to find and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i have updated the xmls

Comment: if i use for-each-group, what will be the value of group-by?

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNP54eU

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, group `otherConstraints` by `CharacterString`. Or by its own string-value, as you did in Muenchian grouping.

Comment: ok noted. i think i need to fix my namespace of the xml elements. i removed them from the example for simplicity. thanks ;)

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you (2.0), as Martin Honnen proposes in the comments:

```
<xsl:template match="MD_LegalConstraints">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="otherConstraints/CharacterString" group-by=".">
        <!-- do something -->
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```